# JavaScript OR operator

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Im having a hard time identifying what is wrong with my code

```
function NavCode() {
    if ((event.keyCode > 31 && event.keyCode < 48) || (event.keyCode > 57 && event.keyCode < 65)|| (event.keyCode > 90 && event.keyCode < 97)|| (event.keyCode > 122 && event.keyCode < 164)||(event.keyCode > 166) )
        event.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }
```

i aim on only allowing 0-9 numbers A-Za-z Letters ñÑ and special characters only
i am sucessfull on implementing 0-9-A-ZazñÑ

Using this code

```
function NavCode() {
        if ((event.keyCode > 31 && event.keyCode < 48) || (event.keyCode > 57 && event.keyCode < 65)|| (event.keyCode > 90 && event.keyCode < 97)|| (event.keyCode > 122 && event.keyCode < 164))
            event.returnValue = false;
            return false;
        }
```

the problem with this is that it also alows ascii characters above 165  eg. `ªº¿`
But when i add `||(event.keyCode > 166)` nothing on the special characters are working  can you help me allow only
**0-9-A-ZazñÑ**?? im really having a hard time debugging the java script as im new to this

Thank you.

Comment: Personally, I would filter the keycodes I do want. You could even pre-populate an object with the valid keycodes. Then you could go `if (!obj[keyCode]) return`.

Comment: im new to java script and i cannot personally understand some of the techniques i can use, i personally depend on the materials i see. bTW thanks for the suggestion @fbynite

Comment: Do you always want to `return false` regardless of the value of event.keyCode? As your code is written, only the first statement `event.returnValue = false;` is executed if the if-statement evaluates to true and skipped if false. The indentation of your code makes it look like you want both statements to be dependent on the outcome from the result of the if-statement.

Comment: No. what you have answered is correct @some im sorry if i cannot understand well Javascript, i just want to return false if the code is not equal to 0-9A-Za-zñÑ and your code below is correct and working for me. Thanks Again!

Comment: We have all been beginners at some point, so don't worry, you too will learn it. A piece of advice: Always use curly braces after an if-statement: `if (something) { statements }` instead of `if (something) statement`. That makes it clear what statements you intend to execute if the if-statement is true. Personally I sometimes break this rule for very short if-statements that fits on one row, like `if (!x) x=1;`. Another piece of advice: Try to make the source code as readable as you can. For example, split a complex if-statement in multiple rows like Karl Anderson did in his answer. Good luck!

Comment: @some thank you for your advice :) i will definitely obey them :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that event.keyCode is a unicode value you could do something like this:

```
if (String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).match(/[^0-9A-Za-zñÑ]/)) {
  event.returnValue = false;
  return false;
}
```

It first converts the event.keyCode to a string (if you have access to the character, use that instead), then it uses a regexp to do a negated match (a `^` as a the first character in a range makes it a negated match)

It is a bit slower to use a regexp instead of checking the values of event.keyCode, but in my opinion it is more readable. Unless your code is running in a tight loop and processing megabytes of data per second, it should not be a problem.

Comment: never heard of this approach well let me try this.

Comment: This is great. never knew i can use some reg ex with this. HEY thanks for this.! :)

Answer (score 2):

You are missing curly braces (`{` and `}`) on the `if`, thus your `return false;` line is always executing, because an `if` without curly braces only conditionally executes the next single line.

Try this:

```
function NavCode() {
    if ((event.keyCode > 31 && event.keyCode < 48) || 
       (event.keyCode > 57 && event.keyCode < 65)|| 
       (event.keyCode > 90 && event.keyCode < 97)|| 
       (event.keyCode > 122 && event.keyCode < 164)) {
        event.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now `return false;` will only execute if the `if` condition is `true`.

Comment: Yes this is working my problem is this also accepts ª¢º special characters. i only want to accept ñÑ in the special character Zone, but the moment i add `||(event.keyCode > 166))` all of the **special** characters are not accepted only numbers and letters, any guidance? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing, curly braces for the if condition and that is the main cause of the issue and if you are not applying curly braces then the statement right after the condition's closing parenthesis, only comes in the 'then' part of the if-then-else statement and all other statements are executed every time whether or not the condition in if is satisfied.